# Why can't I use concatWith after Flux initiation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm newbie and I'm learning Spring Flux. I couldn't understand the Following: Watermelon is being printed here:

```
Flux<String> fruitFlux = Flux.just("Apple", "Banana", "Orange").concatWith(Flux.just("Watermelon"));
fruitFlux.subscribe( System.out::println);
```

But when using the following code, it doesn't get printed:

```
Flux<String> fruitFlux = Flux.just("Apple", "Banana", "Orange");
fruitFlux.concatWith(Flux.just("Watermelon"));
fruitFlux.subscribe( System.out::println);
```

Shouldn't those two code blocks be exactly the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - Flux is immutable, and operators like `concatWith` return a new instance of the Flux modified accordingly. They don't mutate the original publisher.

In your second example, you're ignoring that new instance, so it'll have no effect.

If you did `fruitFlux = fruitFlux.concatWith(Flux.just("Watermelon"));` instead, then you'd see the result you expected.